# Differenze tra "tenere" e "sostenere"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sostenere/) "sostenere" significa

> *tenere sollevata una cosa o una persona sopportandone il peso dal di sotto; sorreggere, tenere sollevato o sospeso;(...) sorreggere una cosa o
>   una persona perché non cada*.

Uno dei significati di "tenere" è

> *avere in mano o tra le mani; stringere qualcuno o qualcosa con le mani, tra
>   le braccia o in altro modo perché non cada, non si muova, non fugga*.

Non mi è chiaro quali siano le differenze di uso tra "sostenere" e "tenere" con questo significato. 
Me le potreste spiegare? Ad esempio, cosa si dovrebbe dire o qual è la differenza tra queste due frasi?

> - Teneva un fazzoletto in mano.
> - Sosteneva un fazzoletto in mano.

Comment: Sostenere  si usa quando c'è l'idea del peso o della difficoltà di tenere qualcosa. Per cui sostenere un fazzoletto suona veramente insolito. Es. *tieni questo libro* o *mi aiuti a sostenere tutti questi libri?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con "sostenere" si sottolinea che si sta facendo un certo sforzo, o comunque si sta mantenendo una postura apposita. Se si parla di "sostenere" un oggetto fisico o una persona, normalmente si implica l'idea che c'è un pericolo di caduta, e "sostenendo" si evita che cada.

In castigliano e catalano esistono i verbi "sostener" e "sostenir", che hanno un ambito di applicazione più ampio rispetto all'italiano "sostenere", ma che comunque include anche il significato italiano. In queste lingue esiste anche un altro verbo che, tra gli altri, può avere il significato di "sostenere": "aguantar".

"Sostenere un fazzoletto" potrebbe evocare un'immagine di un fazzoletto pesante che richiede uno sforzo per evitare che cada, quindi qualcosa di abbastanza insolito, oppure di una persona con un braccio esteso sulla cui mano si trova un fazzoletto; in questo caso si *potrebbe* dire "sostenere il fazzoletto", se si vuole marcare molto il fatto che altrimenti cadrebbe, però direi che si userebbe piuttosto "(sor)reggere" o semplicemente "tenere in mano" un fazzoletto.

Lo sforzo evocato dal verbo "sostenere" non è necessariamente fisico, e si può usare il termine anche in senso metaforico:

> Ha dovuto sostenere (il peso di) una famiglia
>
> Ha sostenuto dei costi molto alti

In alcuni casi si può usare sia "tenere" che "sostenere", anche se c'è sempre una certa differenza di significato (che dipendendo dal contesto può essere anche significativa).

> Teneva lo scatolone (semplicemente ce l'aveva, probabilmente in mano o tra le mani)
>
> Sosteneva lo scatolone (lo scatolone era in qualche modo in equilibrio precario e solo grazie a lui non cadeva)

Comment: Se è così, secondo me esiste differenza tra l'italiano "sostenere" e il castigliano "sostener" o il catalano "sostenir". Puoi trovare molti esempi di uso di "sostener un pañuelo en/con la mano" in Google Books. Ad esempio: https://books.google.es/books?id=kLzGUz7bFB8C&pg=PA291&lpg=PA291&dq=%22sosten%C3%ADa+un+pa%C3%B1uelo%22&source=bl&ots=YdhXl61vJX&sig=WUoouvKKZ2_VSf92vVI_2yGgv9k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Fk4MVb6xH8O1Ub7YgGg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22sosten%C3%ADa%20un%20pa%C3%B1uelo%22&f=false

Comment: Altri esempi: https://books.google.es/books?id=ZYkRAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=%22sosten%C3%ADa+un+pa%C3%B1uelo%22&source=bl&ots=Jlwg-RDs_R&sig=JfXW9DjsNqD-3U3IpO6MzXdk2J4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Fk4MVb6xH8O1Ub7YgGg&ved=0CE0Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22sosten%C3%ADa%20un%20pa%C3%B1uelo%22&f=false, https://books.google.es/books?id=mH4gBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT41&lpg=PT41&dq=%22sosten%C3%ADa+un+pa%C3%B1uelo%22&source=bl&ots=ADPjwXLKL9&sig=6fx_sWvdN_pglqS1mwEpKWS1V-8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dFAMVcG_GoflUvqAg8AE&ved=0CCAQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22sosten%C3%ADa%20un%20pa%C3%B1uelo%22&f=false

Comment: Ancora più esempi: https://books.google.es/books?id=dnha44e1l5QC&pg=PT35&lpg=PT35&dq=%22sosten%C3%ADa+un+pa%C3%B1uelo%22&source=bl&ots=ExQGSxcKeP&sig=-zdxSxG1_a8NtWNtdyPQ4vUGStk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Fk4MVb6xH8O1Ub7YgGg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22sosten%C3%ADa%20un%20pa%C3%B1uelo%22&f=false, https://books.google.es/books?id=7lDE0Z6fYKYC&pg=PT285&lpg=PT285&dq=%22sosten%C3%ADa+un+pa%C3%B1uelo%22&source=bl&ots=QC0vXWoisZ&sig=ilKpj-uDFC69011V6zauxinCMQg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Fk4MVb6xH8O1Ub7YgGg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22sosten%C3%ADa%20un%20pa%C3%B1uelo%22&f=false

Comment: E si possono trovare molti di più.

Comment: Ok, allora non sono 100% equivalenti. Aggiorno la risposta.

Comment: Direi che il *significato* è praticamente lo stesso, l'ambito d'uso invece è più ampio in spagnolo e catalano. In teoria non è sbagliato dire "sostenere un fazzoletto", semplicemente non sarebbe comune.